# What's the word meaning "All thumbs" mentally

Tags: expressions

I've learned *all thumbs* means physically awkward, especially with respect to the hands.

Is there any word or phrase to describe it in mentally?

The opposite of *smooth talker* or *handling other people well.*

Comment: I'd suggest *'inarticulate'*, if you mean clumsiness of expression rather than thought.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the ability to handle people well, I would perhaps use the expression *people skills*. Example: **"He lacks people skills"**.

> people skills: the ability to deal with people well (Longman)

Regarding the opposite of *smooth talker*, I suggest the expression **tongue-tied**. Example: **Why was she always so tongue-tied with this man?**

> tongue-tied: unable to express yourself clearly or fluently (Princeton WordNet)

Comment: in the UK I think 'social-skills' would be better than 'people-skills', though in the context of the question I don't think either is good. However, 'tongue-tied' is IMO really apt.

Answer (score 0):

You could say, they are **conversationally/socially inept**.

> inept: lacking skill or ability: showing a lack of skill or ability : not done well

[**M-W**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inept)